# how to order spark RDD based on two columns

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, rdd

I have below RDD data set:

```
ABC [G4, G3, G1]    3
FFF [G5, G4, G3]    3
CDE [G5,G4,G3,G2]   4
XYZ [G4, G3]    2
```

Need to sort by last column desc first, if last col is same, order by the the fist tuple item desc order. the expected result is

```
CDE [G5,G4,G3,G2]   4
FFF [G5, G4, G3]    3
ABC [G4, G3, G1]    3
XYZ [G4, G3]    2
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sortBy`:

```
rdd.sortBy(r => (r._3, r._2(0)), false)
```

In the above, `r._3` stands for the last column, `r._2(0)` for the first element of the second column (which is an array), and `false` specifies that the order should be descending. Bear in mind though that sorting is an expensive operation due to shuffling.

**Update**

Here's a reproducible example if we assume you start with a `pair rdd`:

```
/// Generate data
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(("ABC","G4"),("ABC","G3"),
                             ("ABC","G1"),("FFF","G5"),
                             ("FFF","G4"),("FFF","G3"),
                             ("CDE","G5"),("CDE","G4"),                             
                             ("CDE","G3"),("CDE","G2"),
                             ("XYZ","G4"),("XYZ","G3")))

/// Put values in a list and calculate its size
val rdd_new = rdd.groupByKey.mapValues(_.toList).map(x => (x._1, x._2, x._2.size))

/// Now this works
rdd_new.sortBy(r => (r._3, r._2(0)), false).collect()
/// Array[(String, List[String], Int)] = Array((CDE,List(G5, G4, G3, G2),4), (FFF,List(G5, G4, G3),3), (ABC,List(G4, G3, G1),3), (XYZ,List(G4, G3),2))
```

Comment: Mtoto, I tried, but result looks not exactly as expected.  (CDE ,[ G5, G4, G3, G2],4)
(ABC ,[ G4, G3, G1],3)
(FFF ,[ G5, G4, G3],3)
(XYZ ,[ G4, G2],2). it order by last column desc correctly, but not correct by first item in array.

Comment: Hi Phoenix/Mtoto, thanks for you help. As I am really new for Spark. I think I did explain it properly this is a result from another process. I opened another stream for the quesiton. would you please help me through below link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41681804/how-to-order-rdd-with-two-columns. thanks for you help.

Comment: What you need to do is share a reproducible example of your dataset, the new question you linked is essentially the same as this one. The problem is probably that your second column is a long string, you'll need to convert this to an array first, then the above should work.

Comment: `rdd.sortBy(r => (r._3, r._1), false)` - try this

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the above answer is not working. It looks fine to me. Just try with this code.

Here is my input:

```
i1,array1,10
i5,array2,50
i4,array3,20
i2,array4,20
```

Code:

```
val idRDD = sc.textFile(inputPath)

val idSOrted = idRDD.map { rec => ((rec.split(",")(2),rec.split(",")(0)),(rec.split(",")(1))) }.sortByKey(false).map(rec=>(rec._1._1,rec._2,rec._1._2))
```

Here is the o/p:

```
(50,array2,i5)
(20,array3,i4)
(20,array4,i2)
(10,array1,i1)
```